# iOS How playing webradio streaming with nativescript-audio plugin?

Tags: ios, nativescript

I am using `nativescript` to develop a web radio app and  `nativescript-audio` plugin to read the stream. On Android I have no problem but on `iOS` the method:

> sharedSession.dataTaskWithUrlCompletionHandler(URL, function(data,
>   response, error)) return with error = {}

Here is part of my **Info.plist**

```html
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
     <key>radioking.com</key>
  <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
   <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
  </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

And here is my url : https://www.radioking.com/play/jobradio
The stream format is mp3

The plugin call :

```
private player  = new TNSPlayer();

public initFromUrl(url : string, autoPlay : boolean = false) {
    // Initialize player
    this.player.initFromUrl({
        audioFile: url,
        loop: false,
        completeCallback: () => {
            this.player.dispose().then(() => { });
        },
        errorCallback: args => { },
        infoCallback:  args => { }
    }).then(() => {
        if (autoPlay) this.player.play();
    });
}
```

Could someone explain me what is wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe,It seems that AVAudioPlayer

Comment: Maybe the value of {} for the error is not really a problem. Maybe, the problem is the AVAudioPlayer class.
The doc say : Use this class for audio playback unless you are playing audio captured from a network stream or require very low I/O latency.
Maybe the AVPlayer could do the job.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I found the solution. As wrote ahead, I replace the AVAudioPlayer by the AVPlayer.

The usefull information in the Info.plist are:

```html
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
   <key>radioking.com</key>
   <dict>
    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
   </dict>
  </dict>
 </dict>
```

And in the plugin, I replace all the code in the playFromUrl by:

```js
    TNSPlayer.prototype.playFromUrl = function (options) {
        var _this = this;
        _this._completeCallback = options.completeCallback;
        _this._errorCallback = options.errorCallback;
        _this._infoCallback = options.infoCallback;

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (options.autoPlay !== false) {
                options.autoPlay = true;
            }
            try {
                var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance();
                var output = audioSession.currentRoute.outputs.lastObject.portType;
                if (output.match(/Receiver/)) {
                    try {
                        audioSession.setCategoryError(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord);
                        audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPortError(AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker);
                        audioSession.setActiveError(true);
                        common_1.TNS_Player_Log("audioSession category set and active");
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        common_1.TNS_Player_Log("setting audioSession category failed");
                    }
                }
                _this._player = AVPlayer.alloc().initWithURL(NSURL.URLWithString(options.audioFile));
                if (_this._player) {
                    _this._player.delegate = _this;
                    common_1.TNS_Player_Log("this._player", _this._player);
                    _this._player.enableRate = true;
                    _this._player.numberOfLoops = options.loop ? -1 : 0;
                    if (options.metering) {
                        common_1.TNS_Player_Log("enabling metering...");
                        _this._player.meteringEnabled = true;
                    }
                    if (options.autoPlay) {
                        _this._player.play();
                    }
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    reject();
                }
            }
            catch (ex) {
                if (_this._errorCallback) {
                    _this._errorCallback({ ex: ex });
                }
                reject(ex);
            }
        });
    };
```

With this code, all the controller actions keep working.
online mp3 and web streaming work correctly.

Comment: I also had to set _this._player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false; to get it to start streaming more quickly.